# How to interpolate missing data in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a data set like the following. We only have data for the last day of a month I am trying to interpolate rest of it, is it the right way of doing it?

```
Date  Australia China
2011-01-01  NaN   NaN
2011-01-02  NaN   NaN
-           -     -
-           -     -
2011-01-31  4.75  5.81
2011-02-01  NaN   NaN
2011-02-02  NaN   NaN
-           -     -
-           -     -
2011-02-28  4.75  5.81
2011-03-01  NaN   NaN
2011-03-02  NaN   NaN
-           -     -
-           -     -
2011-03-31  4.75  6.06
2011-04-01  NaN   NaN
2011-04-02  NaN   NaN
-           -     -
-           -     -
2011-04-30  4.75  6.06
```

For interpolate this dataframe to find missing NaN values I am using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col="Date")
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).ffill().bfill()
```

But I am getting an error "TypeError: Cannot interpolate with all NaNs."

What might be wrong here, how I can fix this?

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory. You can try by dropping NaN as per this http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but instead of NaNs what can i fill in those rows?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan good answers have already been given, I think. Your data is quite sparse, so you may want to question whether it is a good idea to actually interpolate such huge amounts of data. How sure are you that those values will be somewhat correct?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try convert `dataframe` to `float` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col=['Date'], parse_dates=['Date'])

print df

            Australia  China
Date                        
2011-01-31       4.75   5.81
2011-02-28       4.75   5.81
2011-03-31       4.75   6.06
2011-04-30       4.75   6.06

df = df.reindex(pd.date_range("2011-01-01", "2011-10-31"), fill_value="NaN")

#convert to float
df = df.astype(float)

df = df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).ffill().bfill()
```

```
print df

            Australia  China
2011-01-01       4.75   5.81
2011-01-02       4.75   5.81
2011-01-03       4.75   5.81
2011-01-04       4.75   5.81
2011-01-05       4.75   5.81
2011-01-06       4.75   5.81
2011-01-07       4.75   5.81
2011-01-08       4.75   5.81
2011-01-09       4.75   5.81
2011-01-10       4.75   5.81
2011-01-11       4.75   5.81
2011-01-12       4.75   5.81
2011-01-13       4.75   5.81
2011-01-14       4.75   5.81
2011-01-15       4.75   5.81
2011-01-16       4.75   5.81
2011-01-17       4.75   5.81
2011-01-18       4.75   5.81
2011-01-19       4.75   5.81
2011-01-20       4.75   5.81
2011-01-21       4.75   5.81
2011-01-22       4.75   5.81
2011-01-23       4.75   5.81
2011-01-24       4.75   5.81
2011-01-25       4.75   5.81
2011-01-26       4.75   5.81
2011-01-27       4.75   5.81
2011-01-28       4.75   5.81
2011-01-29       4.75   5.81
2011-01-30       4.75   5.81
...               ...    ...
2011-10-02       4.75   6.06
2011-10-03       4.75   6.06
2011-10-04       4.75   6.06
2011-10-05       4.75   6.06
2011-10-06       4.75   6.06
2011-10-07       4.75   6.06
2011-10-08       4.75   6.06
2011-10-09       4.75   6.06
2011-10-10       4.75   6.06
2011-10-11       4.75   6.06
2011-10-12       4.75   6.06
2011-10-13       4.75   6.06
2011-10-14       4.75   6.06
2011-10-15       4.75   6.06
2011-10-16       4.75   6.06
2011-10-17       4.75   6.06
2011-10-18       4.75   6.06
2011-10-19       4.75   6.06
2011-10-20       4.75   6.06
2011-10-21       4.75   6.06
2011-10-22       4.75   6.06
2011-10-23       4.75   6.06
2011-10-24       4.75   6.06
2011-10-25       4.75   6.06
2011-10-26       4.75   6.06
2011-10-27       4.75   6.06
2011-10-28       4.75   6.06
2011-10-29       4.75   6.06
2011-10-30       4.75   6.06
2011-10-31       4.75   6.06

[304 rows x 2 columns]
```

And you can omit `ffill()`, because `NaN` are only in first rows of `dataframe`:

```
df = df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).ffill().bfill()
```

to:

```
df = df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).bfill()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try dropping NaN from the dataset before interpolating.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col="Date")
df = df.dropna()
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).ffill().bfill()
```

Comment: Those NaN rows was not in CSV I have added it using the code df = df.reindex(pd.date_range("2011-01-01", "2011-10-31"), fill_value=np.nan) .Otherwise how I can fill those rows?