# Resample data monthly in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large csv file example below,

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Ene_E/Desktop/Data/data.csv')
data.head()
```

---

```
          name  year  value
0  Afghanistan  1800    603
1      Albania  1800    667
2      Algeria  1800    715
3      Andorra  1800   1200
4       Angola  1800    618
```

---

```
data.tail()
```

---

```
            name  year  value
46508  Venezuela  2040  17600
46509    Vietnam  2040  12300
46510      Yemen  2040   3960
46511     Zambia  2040   6590
46512   Zimbabwe  2040   3210
```

my large CSV has over 200 countries and their data recorded annually from 1800 - 2040, my goal is to resample this data to monthly and interpolate value column as shown below, I have used Afghanistan, the year 1800 to illustrate how my desired end result,

**Expected output:**

```
name               date    value
Afghanistan        Jan     1800   start_value
Afghanistan        Feb     1800   .
Afghanistan        Mar     1800   . 
Afghanistan        May     1800   .
Afghanistan        Jun     1800   .
Afghanistan        Jul     1800   .This column is interpolated smoothly
Afghanistan        Aug     1800   .
Afghanistan        Sep     1800   .
Afghanistan        Oct     1800   .
Afghanistan        Nov     1800   .
Afghanistan        Dec     1800   603(end value in that year)
```

I want all my data resampled as in the above in python because this only way my model will work.
NB: the dates should take above format.

I have tried severally without success,

```
data['year'] = pd.to_datetime(data.year, format='%Y')
head(data)
```

---

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    head(data) NameError: name 'head' is not defined
```

---

```
data.head()
```

---

```
          name                year  value
0  Afghanistan 1800-01-01 00:00:00    603
1      Albania 1800-01-01 00:00:00    667
2      Algeria 1800-01-01 00:00:00    715
3      Andorra 1800-01-01 00:00:00   1200
4       Angola 1800-01-01 00:00:00    618
```

---

```
data.resample('1M', how='interpolate')
```

---

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    data.resample('1M', how='interpolate')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8145, in resample
    base=base, key=on, level=level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1251, in resample
    return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1381, in _get_resampler
    "but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__)
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

---

```
data.groupby(name).resample('1M', how='interpolate')
```

---

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    data.groupby(name).resample('1M', how='interpolate')
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693079/python-pandas-dataframe-interpolate-missing-data <-- does this helps

Comment: data.groupby('name').resample('1M', how='interpolate') not name it should be 'name'

Comment: Do all your readings start in Jan and end in Dec or you want the minimum starting date labelled as Start and max as End?

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally assign name for where date values are missing using [np.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

```
data['value']=np.where(data['date'].isna(), 'This column is interpolated smoothly', '')#.data.ffill(axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Forward fill missing dates

```
data['date']=pd.to_datetime(data['date']).ffill()
```

Group by date and reset back to dataframe

```
data.set_index('date', inplace=True)
data['value'] = np.where( data.index.month== 1, 'start_value', data['value']) 
data['value'] = np.where( data.index.month== 12, 'End_value', data['value'])
data.groupby(data.index.month)['name', 'value'].ffill().reset_index().sort_values(by=['name','date'], ascending=True).drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

@DEVELOPER_ONE I am not familiar with interpolate or resample, but I felt like giving it a go a different way. I literally produced similar to what your desired output is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Zimbabwe','Afghanistan', 
                             'Albania', 'Zimbabwe'],
                     'year':[1800,1800,1800,2040,2040,2040],
                     'value' : [603,667,59,2415,2804,3210]
                     })
df_year_unique = pd.DataFrame(data['year'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))
df_name_unique = pd.DataFrame(data['name'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))
df_month_unique = pd.DataFrame({'Month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                                          'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']})
df_name = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df_name_unique]*len(
df_month_unique)*len(df_year_unique),
ignore_index=True)).sort_values('name').reset_index(drop=True)
df_month = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df_month_unique]*len(
df_year_unique)*len(df_name_unique),
ignore_index=True))
df_year = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df_year_unique]*len(
df_month_unique)*len(df_name_unique),                          
ignore_index=True)).sort_values('year').reset_index(drop=True)
df_year_month = pd.merge(df_month, df_year, how='inner', left_index=True, 
right_index=True)
df_year_month_name = pd.merge(df_year_month, df_name, how='inner', left_index=True, 
right_index=True)
df = pd.merge(df_year_month_name, data, how='left', on=['name','year'])
df['value'] = np.where(df['Month'] != 'Dec', '.', df['value'])
df['value'] = np.where(df['Month'] == 'Jan', 'start_value', df['value'])
df['value'] = np.where(df['Month'] == 'Jul', '.This column is interpolated smoothly', 
df['value'])
df
```