# Is there a way to calculate between two value of NaN value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm having a trouble to code into finding in between values in pandas dataframe.
the dataframe:

| value |
| --- |
| 30 |
| NaN |
| NaN |
| 25 |
| NaN |
| 20 |
| NaN |
| NaN |
| NaN |
| NaN |
| 15 |
| ... |

the formula is like this:

`value before nan - ((value before nan - value after nan)/div by no. of nan in between the values)`

example of expected value should be like this:

`30 - (30-25)/2 = 27.5`
`27.5 - (27.5-25)/1 = 25`

so the expected dataframe will look like this:

| value | expected value |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 30 |
| NaN | 27.5 |
| NaN | 25 |
| 25 | 25 |
| NaN | 20 |
| 20 | 20 |
| NaN | 18.75 |
| NaN | 17.5 |
| NaN | 16.25 |
| NaN | 15 |
| 15 | 15 |
| ... | ... |

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to interpolate data between NaNs (although if you are your formula isn't quite right). If so look at df.interpolate function: check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/34694772/2794417

Comment: How is the third `nan` 22.5? 25 - (25 - 20)/1 = 20?

Comment: i'm still new to pandas and dataframe. i'm not familiar with the interpolate method.. for now, i only know to do for loop. @GalodoLeste

Comment: sorry sir, i'm mistakenly calculate it. @Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can generalize your formula into two parts:

1. Any `nan` right before a non-nan is just same as that number

- {value-before-nan} - ({value-before-nan} - {value-after-nan})/1 = {value-after-nan}

2. Rest of `nan` are linear interpolation.

So you can use `bfill` with `interpolate`:

```
df.bfill(limit=1).interpolate()
```

Output:

```
    value
0   30.00
1   27.50
2   25.00
3   25.00
4   20.00
5   20.00
6   18.75
7   17.50
8   16.25
9   15.00
10  15.00
```