# How to plot NaN values as gaps in a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, nan, scatter-plot

I have a figure with six subplot control charts from a Pandas dataframe, currently plotted by index and I'd like to plot them against a datetime value.  The raw data (from an XML file) contains blank values, given as '-' which I convert to numpy NaN:

`df[y[0]].replace({'-': np.nan}, inplace =True)`

I can't use zeroes, as I need to run stats on them, including a moving range calculation, which is used to create control limits. The results are genuine blanks, not zeroes.

The indexed output works very well:

[image: Set of six subplot control charts, plotted against index]

I would like to plot the same data against a timestamp value (which is non-regular) in the df, but the NaN values are causing the error `x and y must be the same size` as there are more timestamps than there are values once NaNs are removed.

The error occurs (not surprisingly) at `df.plot.scatter(y = y[0], ax=axes[0], x = 'TIMESTAMP')`

As the NaN values don't appear at the same time point in all six subplots, it is important to maintain the time axis and just leave a gap for the NaN values; I do not want to just drop the whole row as there is often just one NaN with five valid points at any given time.

Sample data:

```py
data = {'TIMESTAMP': ['01/07/2023 08:04:11', '01/07/2023 08:04:37', '01/07/2023 08:04:53', '01/07/2023 08:05:06', '01/07/2023 08:05:18', '01/07/2023 08:05:29', '01/07/2023 08:05:40', '01/07/2023 08:05:50', '01/07/2023 08:06:01', '01/07/2023 08:06:12', '01/07/2023 08:06:22', '01/07/2023 08:06:33', '01/07/2023 08:06:43'],
        'y1': ['107.08', '107.54', '107.18', '-', '106.92', '107.16', '107.46', '107.68', '107.84', '107.88', '108.1', '108.06', '108.2'],
        'y2': [107.12, 107.0, 107.92, 107.78, 106.96, 107.36, 107.58, 107.66, 107.92, 107.8, 107.94, 108.2, 108.12],
        'y3': ['107.66', '107.16', '106.92', '108.14', '106.96', '-', '107.54', '107.58', '107.72', '107.82', '107.96', '108.04', '108.12'],
        'y4': ['107.48', '107.6', '107.82', '107.78', '107.02', '-', '107.46', '107.48', '107.76', '107.82', '107.88', '108.02', '108.08'],
        'y5': ['107.38', '107.6', '107.6', '107.72', '107.48', '107.82', '107.9', '108.12', '108.22', '-', '108.7', '107.98', '107.94'],
        'y6': [107.44, 107.62, 107.48, 107.56, 107.46, 107.72, 107.82, 108.08, 108.06, 108.2, 108.18, 108.36, 108.46]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
              TIMESTAMP      y1      y2      y3      y4      y5      y6
0   01/07/2023 08:04:11  107.08  107.12  107.66  107.48  107.38  107.44
1   01/07/2023 08:04:37  107.54  107.00  107.16   107.6   107.6  107.62
2   01/07/2023 08:04:53  107.18  107.92  106.92  107.82   107.6  107.48
3   01/07/2023 08:05:06       -  107.78  108.14  107.78  107.72  107.56
4   01/07/2023 08:05:18  106.92  106.96  106.96  107.02  107.48  107.46
5   01/07/2023 08:05:29  107.16  107.36       -       -  107.82  107.72
6   01/07/2023 08:05:40  107.46  107.58  107.54  107.46   107.9  107.82
7   01/07/2023 08:05:50  107.68  107.66  107.58  107.48  108.12  108.08
8   01/07/2023 08:06:01  107.84  107.92  107.72  107.76  108.22  108.06
9   01/07/2023 08:06:12  107.88  107.80  107.82  107.82       -  108.20
10  01/07/2023 08:06:22   108.1  107.94  107.96  107.88   108.7  108.18
11  01/07/2023 08:06:33  108.06  108.20  108.04  108.02  107.98  108.36
12  01/07/2023 08:06:43   108.2  108.12  108.12  108.08  107.94  108.46
```

Answer (score -1):

> Dealing with missing or NaN (Not-a-Number) values in your data is an
> essential step in data preprocessing. Especially as you are attempting a moving range calculation as a next step.

So, to begin with I would propose you do not try to leave this places empty for visualization purposes (you could print white points if you wanted to), but already think about your next step and how you need to handle them to be able to do your calculations - otherwise you will only be moving your problem one step down the pipeline. For the visualization you could then obviously mark (color or shape of the dot) the changed NaN values accordingly, so it is still visible that these have been approximated and are not from your primary sensors or data sources.

**1. Global Imputation**

Replace NaN values with the mean, median, or most frequent value of the respective feature. This is a simple and quick way to fill missing values, especially for numerical features.

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame with NaN values
data = {'column_name': [1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Mean imputation for 'column_name'
mean_value = df['column_name'].mean() #3
df['column_name'].fillna(mean_value, inplace=True)
```

**2. Local Interpolation**

Use interpolation techniques (e.g., linear interpolation) to estimate missing values based on surrounding data points. This is often used for time series data.

```
# Sample DataFrame with NaN values
data = {'column_name': [1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Interpolation for 'column_name'
df['column_name'].interpolate(method='linear', inplace=True) # 3
```

You know your data best, so whether 1. or 2. or which interpolation method to use, is up to you. Or should be treated as a hyperparameter in your overall model design process.

Comment: This answer is not what the OP asked for. They do not want to fill nan. They want a scatterplot with a blank where the nan is, plotted against TIMESTAMP, instead of the index (as is currently shown). If replacing NaN was the question, it would be closed as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38134012/7758804, https://stackoverflow.com/q/34693079/7758804, etc.

Comment: Thanks Trenton, I did just consider to delete. In my opinion however my answer can anyways provide value, just as your links that extend my answer - I appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

The OP is plotting against the dataframe `index`, but wants to plot each column in a subplot against the `'TIMESTAMP'` column, **and does not want to fill `NaN`.**

Any column with a `'-'` is imported as an `object dtype`, not a `float`, so after replacing values with `np.nan`, the columns must be converted to `float dtype`.

The current code implies an iterative approach to cleaning the data and plotting, and the OP states `NaNs` were removed, which causes a length mismatch with the `'TIMESTAMP'` column, and results in `x and y must be the same size`.

As shown in the following code, columns with `NaN` will plot against the `'TIMESTAMP'` column without issue, and, as requested, there will be a blank space corresponding to the `NaN` location.

**Tested in `python 3.11.5`, `pandas 2.1.0`, `matplotlib 3.7.2`**

```py
# convert TIMESTAMP to a datatime
df.TIMESTAMP = pd.to_datetime(df.TIMESTAMP)

# replace all '-' with np.nan
df.replace({'-': np.nan}, inplace=True)

# a list of the columns to plot on y
cols = df.columns[1:]

# convert the columns to floats
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float)

# create the figure and axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(cols), figsize=(8, 8), tight_layout=True, sharex=True)

# iterate through each column to plot on one of the subplots
for ax, col in zip(axes, cols):

    # plot the dataframe column
    df.plot(kind='scatter', x='TIMESTAMP', y=col, ax=ax)
```

- The format of the xtick labels will change depending on the range of the independent variable.

[image]